# How can I retrieve Constituency_Name from This object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How can I retrieve `Constituency_Name` from this object.

```
[{"Constituency_ID":148,"Constituency_Name":"NA-160"},
{"Constituency_ID":151,"Constituency_Name":"NA-163"},
{"Constituency_ID":149,"Constituency_Name":"NA-161"},
{"Constituency_ID":150,"Constituency_Name":"NA-162"}]
```

```
data: { Constituency_ID: Constituency_Name }, success: function (cities)
          $('#Constituency_ID').html("");
```

```
$.each(cities, function (key, value) {

                var a = cities.length;
               var we= value[0].map(function (element, index) {
                    return element.Constituency_Name;
                })
                ///parsedData
                var select = document.getElementById('#Constituency_ID');

               // var pos =value[0].Constituency_Name.indexOf("NA");
                option = document.createElement('option'); 
                option.text = we;
                option.value = value[0].Constituency_ID;

                $('#Constituency_ID').append(option);

            });



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you using to interpret the JSON? Are you looking for a javascript solution?

Comment: Yes i want JS Solution for acces constituency name on succes function

Answer (score 1):

```
    var p = [{"Constituency_ID":148,"Constituency_Name":"NA-160"},{"Constituency_ID":151,"Constituency_Name":"NA-163"},{"Constituency_ID":149,"Constituency_Name":"NA-161"},{"Constituency_ID":150,"Constituency_Name":"NA-162"}]

    var countryNameArray = p.map(function(element,index){
    return element.Constituency_Name;
    })
console.log(countryNameArray[0]) // prints NA-160
```

Comment: Sir  Manoj Yadav r u here?

Comment: @EhtishamZaki Yes.

Comment: Sir Plz Help .I waisted 3 hours for acces it but failed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45888969/4948383
add above answer to your success method in ajax

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

```
 cities.forEach(function(element,index{
$('#Constituency_ID').append('<option>'+element.Constituency_Name+ '</option>')
        })
```

if you wants to add value to your options then please use this

```
cities.forEach(function(element,index{
    $('#Constituency_ID').append('<option value='+element.Constituency_ID+'>'+element.Constituency_Name+ '</option>')
            })
```

Comment: Welcome @EhtishamZaki